# Unable to inject AngularJS $templateCache into run method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, angularjs-templates

I'm attempting to inject and access the angular $templateCache service as per the docs here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache. I'm also attempting to inject my own service.

```
var myApp = angular.module('my-app');

myApp.run([$templateCache, 'MyService', function($templateCache, myService) {
    var contentPromise = myService.getContent();
    contentPromise.then(function(content) {
        $templateCache.put('myTemplate', content);
    });
}]);
```

MyService injects just fine but $templateCache does not. I'm getting the following error:

> ReferenceError: $templateCache is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change

```
myApp.run(['$templateCache', 'MyService', function($templateCache, MyService) {
```

instead

```
myApp.run([$templateCache, 'MyService', function($templateCache, myService) {
```

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I missed that - I was too busy trying to follow another code example and missed the ticks ''. Although assigning 'MyService' to 'myService' variable works.

Comment: @samoussa.usa run jshint grunt task :)